# Callback function inside Deferred objects

Tags: jquery, deferred

I'm trying to follow some javascript lessons where there is an implementation of Deferred.
This is the core of the code

```
getData = function (options) {
  return $.Deferred(function (def) {

    var results = options.results;                    

    getFunction({
      success: function (smt) {                                
        results("test");
        def.resolve(results);
        debugger;
      },
      error: function (response) {                                    
        def.reject();
      }
    }); 

  }).promise();
},
```

Now the question is.. when i call this function from outside like:

```
$.when(somthing.getData(options)).
   done(alert(options.results));

debugger;
```

It happens that FIRSTLY reach the debugger outside the $.when call, and THEN touch the one inside callback SUCCESS function inside the Deferred object...

I don't get it.. shouldn't be the promise done only when def.resolve(results) is reached?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's correct except for the last line:

```
$.when(somthing.getData(options)).done(alert(options.results));
debugger;
```

You call `alert` ( and `debugger` ) immediatly here. What you want is to pass a callback to `done` like this:

```
$.when(somthing.getData(options))
.done(function(){
    alert(options.results);
    debugger;
});
```

Comment: Thank freakish.. that worked like a charm.. Can i ask you why?.. I thought that the function inside DONE was already a callback function... why do i have to define a function like that to call my function?...

Comment: `.done` accepts a function. What you passed to `.done` is not a function, but a result of calling `alert()` ( note the order: first alert is called, then it's result is passed to `.done` ) which is undefined ( that's what alert returns ). It's like doing `.done("test")`. What does it mean? What JavaScript is supposed to do with a string? You want to pass a function to `.done`, so JavaScript will know: "oh, I've received a function, I can call it once `when` is done".